# Xcode debug doesn't print all fields of objects

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a `indexPath` with type `NSIndexPath` in the code below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

In debugger, indexPath don't display some field like section or row.
It try `po` and `p` but it shown

```
(lldb) p indexPath.row  
error: property 'row' not found on object of  
type 'NSIndexPath *' error: 1 errors parsing expression   

(lldb) po  
indexPath.row error: property 'row' not found on object of type  
'NSIndexPath *' error: 1 errors parsing expression

po indexPath  
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200416> {length = 2, path = 4 - 1}
```

What should I do to enable it? Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: with **po** all other value is print ?

Comment: @Vvk in my picture, you will see the section and row don't print

Comment: @PhanVănLinh actually PO is used for print object so it print whole object. You are try to print the one field of the index path so it is not possible

Answer (score 4):

`po` is usually used for printing object description

For value, try to use `p` instead: `p indexPath.row`

Comment: `p indexPath.row` don't work with me :(